# How to perform a mysql query after reading session values

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am using this script to read a value in a session, then I want to query the database about this value :

```
    <?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"] ;
echo "Your user_id is: $user_id \n" ;

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id='%s' ", $user_id);
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $email =  $row['email'] . "\n";
    echo "Your e-mail adress is : $email \n" ;
}
?>
```

I get this when I test the page with my browser: 
Your user_id is: 1430

Invalid query: Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Whole query: SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id='1430'

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to your database server first and select a database using [`mysql_connect`](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) and [`mysql_select_db`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php). The `mysql_query` function will try to open a connection with default parameters, or as the manual puts it:

> If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.

Hence, PHP is trying to connect to localhost with username "nobody" and no password.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_select_db('my_database');
```

..and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

The username `nobody` needs a password to use the database. The error clearly states this. The user **nobody** for the server **localhost** has its **access denied** when using **no password**

`Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

OR, although this is unlike, the machine you are running your code from does not have access to the machine that it running the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure your id is an INTEGER, so the following should work:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id=%d ", $user_id);
```

There also seems to be a problem with authenticating against the database. Have you successfully connected to the database using [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect)?

Comment: This isn't the case, because the query is being built correctly, you can see this from the error `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='1430' `

Comment: I didn't say it's build incorrectly. I just say that the id='whatever' will fail, because he's comparing INTEGER with CHAR/TEXT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [connect](http://php.net/mysql_connect) to the database host with a valid user/password before querying:

```
mysql_connect($mysqlHost, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPassword);
```

Then, you need to [select](http://php.net/mysql_select_db) the database:

```
mysql_select_db($mysqlDatabase) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first connect to a db :

```
<?php

$username = "";
$password = "";
$hostname = ""; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");


$selected = mysql_select_db("DBNAMEGOESHERE",$dbhandle)
  or die("End");


}

?>
```